# Does function call is replaced with function definition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the below code, and it prints 42.

```
{
  let number = 42;
  function printNumber() {
  console.log(number);
}
function log() {
  let number = 54;
  printNumber();
}
// Prints 42
log();
}
```

This output brought me to wonder the function call is replaced by function definition or not?

I tried removing the **"number"** variable declaration in the beginning of the program to see if it reads the "number" defined inside the log() function but it returned reference error,

```
    { 
//let number = 42;
function printNumber() {
  console.log(number);
}
function log() {
  let number = 54;
  printNumber();
}
// Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined
log();
}
```

I want to understand how the function call is interpreted and how the scope is determined that if a function printNumber() is called inside another function log() then how is it not supposed to use the variable declared inside the function log() from where it is called.

Comment: you commented out number and it is now only in the scope of the log function so, you cannot detect it in the scope of the printNumber definition.

Comment: JavaScript scoping rules apply here. As a rule of thumb, the syntactic structure of the source code determines visibility of variables, as opposed to the flow of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `log()` you are creating a new variable named `number`, not setting the one in the block scope.

```js
{
  let number = 42;
  function printNumber() {
    console.log(number);
  }
  function log() {
    let number = 54;  //< This is a NEW variable.
    printNumber();
  }
  function log2() {
    number = 54;     //< This is using the block-scope variable.
    printNumber();
  }
  
  log();  // Prints 42
  log2(); // Prints 54
}
```

Comment: You are right! in log2() function we are ultimately editing the value of number variable declared at the top which is accessible to printNumber.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to scope and context in Javscript.

```js
{
       let number = 42;
       function printNumber() {
          console.log(number);  //as it does not have number in its function scope it will check for it in global score which is equal to 42 and prints it
       }
    
      function log() {
        let number = 54;  //log defined variable number, but its score is limited to log only, and can not be accessed in printNumber, (see printNumber description)
        printNumber();
      }
      
      log();  // Prints 42
    }
```

**SECOND CASE:**

```js
    {
       let number = 42;
       function printNumber(number) {
          console.log(number);  //in this case, it does have a local variable number so it will use that variable
       }
    
      function log() {
        let number = 54;  //log defined variable number, but its score is limited to log only, 
        printNumber(number);  //we are passing number to printNumber
      }
    
      log();  // Prints 54
    }
```